# Looking for a camscanner for windows 10

Tags: pdf

I need something that scans a big pdf (1000 pages) like camscanner does but for windows 10. Linux is ok as well as I've multiple VMs. I already have a pdf that is dark, I need to lighten it like camscanner does. I don't need to take pictures.